# Can I get the monthly cycle using moment.js for every months?

Tags: javascript, node.js, moment-timezone

i want to run a query from last month's  15 January and current month's 14th February. and i want to run the logic in such a way that this follows for next months also like from 15th February to 14th March. I certainly don't know how to proceed with this problem using moment.js

like I want to get the last months' 15th date and current months 14th for each month. think like a cycle where the cycle starts from 15th of the previous months and ends with this months 14th

Comment: Please provide some examples for what you want to achieve. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a moment instance called `date` the following method calculates the 15th of the previous month to the 14th of the current month (where "current" date is `date` parameter):

```
function getRange(date){
  var start = date.clone().startOf("month").add(-1,'months').add(14,'days');
  var end = date.clone().startOf("month").add(13,"days");
  return [start,end];
}
```

A live example with 2 test cases can be seen in the demo below.

```js
var testArr = [
   moment(),
   moment({y:2019,M:11,d:31}) // 31 december 2019. (Yes months are zero based!)
];

for(var i=0;i<testArr.length;i++){
    var [start,end] = getRange(testArr[i]);
    console.log(start,' --> ',end);
}


function getRange(date){
  var start = date.clone().startOf("month").add(-1,'months').add(14,'days');
  var end = date.clone().startOf("month").add(13,"days");
  return [start,end];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please simplify this solution? I have understood the solution yet i am requesting you

Comment: i got it sorry if i have disturbed you

Answer (score 0):

this problem will be solved in this way I am adding simplicity in @Jamiec

```
const date = moment();
const start = date.clone().startOf("month").add(-1,'months').add(14,'days');
const end = date.clone().startOf("month").add(13,"days");
console.log(start,end)
```